# Can I use two values in a switch case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I want test the values of both `a` and `b`. Is there anyway I can `switch` on both their values simultaneously?

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

switch (a) {
   case '1':
      printf("one");
      break;
   case '2':
      printf("two");
      break;
   case '3':
      printf("three");
      break;
}
```

Comment: `case '1':` --> `case 1:`

Comment: `switch (10*a + b) { case 11: break; case 42: break; default: break; }`

Comment: If `a` and `b` have limited range, you can mathematically combine them. For instance if these are from `0` to `9`, you can make `c = a * 10 + b` and switch on `c`.

Comment: @pmg Great minds think alike :D

Comment: why do not use two `switch` to test (one for `a`, one for `b`)? It's more simple ? or you want something different ?

Comment: @Vipultiwari990 Describe or show how you are going to use such a switch statement with two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve that indirectly. If `a` and `b` are both `int`, you can do the followings

```
long long c;
c = 65536*a+b;
switch (c){
    case whatever:
           whatever;
}
```

However note that this solution is not generic, as you can not do this on random types, say pointers for example; but you may be able to implement a solution specific to a type.